# I want to append a string to an existing column of sqlite. Is that possible, if yes then how

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to add the strings dynamically into a single column of my sqlite database.
 please any one suggest me how to do this.

Comment: Get the value, append your string to it, then update you table with the new value

Comment: Please tell me how to append the string to a particular column.

Comment: I mean, code for how to append multiple strings to a single cell separated by commas.

Comment: What have you tried? Google Sqlite tutorials. Retrieve the string value by using a select statement, append your multiple strings to it, then update your table with the new value using an update statement. You need to show that your tried something

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON o XML in the column. Create a document JSON, add string, save the row. After, get a row, get JSON of column, add new string in JSON and save it again.

Answer (score 0):

```java
db.execSQL("UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = MyColumn || ?",
           new Object[] { myString });
```